# Event Horizon Tunnel

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Regarding the following short animation of a merger between a large and small black hole:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ&feature=youtu.be

The colored surfaces are meant to be the horizons (points of no return).

I'm having a hard time understanding the reason for that tunnel that extends between the two momentarily.

[image: One]

[image: Two]

Credits: SXS Collaboration

After the tunnel forms (2nd image) consider a ray of light that passes exactly through the midpoint of the tunnel (barycenter of the BH's I assume...?), on a path perpendicular to the tunnel.   In the case of two planetary bodies or stars in this configuration, the light would be passing through a kind of "saddle" or Lagrange point of gravitational potential, equally balanced between the two massive bodies, and its trajectory would be unaffected.  Why is this not the case for the black holes?

One reason  I can speculate is: looking dynamically rather than statically at the situation, the region inside the tunnel is not, at that instant, at an inescapable gravitational potential. But the BH's converge so fast (e.g. microseconds) that a perpendicular light ray will not have time to travel enough distance before it *is* engulfed by the inescapable potential of either BH. But I've no idea if that's correct.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: In Newtonian gravity, the potential at any point between two stars is a sum of their potentials there. So you would get a similar tunnel shape. Your confusion must be based on thinking of the gravitational acceleration being zero at some point in between. However the horizon refers to the potential, not acceleration, and the absolute value of the potential is higher, not lower, between the stars. Light not being able to cross the horizon has nothing to do specifically with the tunnel, but is the effect of the time dilation at the horizon. Your question is based on a wrong premise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a test mass near the tunnel. It's not pulled towards the bigger black hole or towards the smaller black hole, but towards the 'tunnel'. The test mass could orbit the tunnel, which we might call a Lagrange tube. Except if test mass goes too close to the tube, then orbiting is impossible, because orbiting is not possible in a place where gravitational potential is too low.

Well, gravitational potential may be too low for orbiting even quite far away from the 'tunnel'. But let's say circling the tube in a powerful rocket is possible. Doesn't the Webb space telescope orbit a Lagrange point?